# Prevent Cordova Android from running in the background

Tags: android, cordova

Is there a way to stop or pause a Cordova app when it moves to the background?

With simple test code

```
var app = {
    // Application Constructor
    initialize: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady.bind(this), false);
    },

    // deviceready Event Handler
    //
    // Bind any cordova events here. Common events are:
    // 'pause', 'resume', etc.
    onDeviceReady: function() {
        this.receivedEvent('deviceready');
    },

    // Update DOM on a Received Event
    receivedEvent: function(id) {
        var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
        var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
        var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

        listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
        receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

        console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
        setInterval(function(){
            console.log("Stilling running at",new Date());
        },1);
    }
};

app.initialize();
```

The interval keeps running after the app is minimized on the phone.  Is there any way to pause the app like it used to in older versions of Android?

This is an over simplified example of a much larger app that uses PouchDb but has the same problem with javascript continuing to run even after the app is minimized or the screen is turned off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you actually mean by "pause the app".  Apps are managed by the phone's OS and the behavior varies by device and OS version.  What you can do is run code whenever the app is sent to the background and/or when it is restored to the foreground.  To do so you can use the pause and resume events that cordova generates.

You can find the events documents here: [Cordova Events](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/cordova/events/events.html)

To run code when the app is sent to the background

```
document.addEventListener("pause", onPause, false);

function onPause() {
  // Stop any intervals here along with any other code to "pause" the app
}
```

To run code when the app is restored to the foreground

```
document.addEventListener("resume", onResume, false);

function onResume() {
  // Start up any intervals you want along with any other code to restore the app
}
```

Comment: The app has a lot of intervals, websockets, etc. So pausing and resuming them is tricky.  Don't suppose there is one of those special hidden cordova tricks to allow webview to pause again like it used to?

Comment: Unfortunately there isn't anything I'm aware of.